# Can I use a FormRequest inside another?

Tags: laravel

Can I use a FormRequest inside another?
Something like:

```
class StoreRestaurantRequest extends FormRequest
{
    ....

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'opening_hours' => new OpeningHoursRequest // -> other FormRequest
        ];
    }
}
```

```
class OpeningHoursRequest extends FormRequest
{
    .....

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            "day" => ['required','integer'],
            "opening_hour" => ['integer',],
            "opening_minute" => ['integer'],
            "closing_hour" => ['integer'],
            "closing_minute" => ['integer'],
        ];
    }
}
```

I am not getting any errors but validation doesn't seem to work.
How can I keep thoose rules seperated?

Comment: Even if such code did work, what are you expecting it to validate? Is opening_hours an array containing day, opening_hour, etc? It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, but no: passing an object as a validation rule will not work.

Comment: Yes it's and array, I used traits and 'opening_hours.*.day' => ...

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you shouldn't do like that. I'd use [traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) for your case

Comment: Thanks for the advice, using traits I got it :)